# Does IIS 6 Virtual SMTP Server support UTF/Unicode Subject Lines

Tags: iis, smtp

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5 hosting a bunch of websites. These websites relay email through the IIS 6 Manager's Virtual SMTP Server.

**I'm trying to verify whether or not this setup will allow Unicode Characters in the subject lines.**

I can find references ot IIS6 supporting unicode and IIS 6 FTP service supporting unicode but cannot find a difinitive reference as to whether UTF/Unicode is supported when sending mail through the IIS 6 Virtual SMTP Server.

Here's the reference I found discussing general unicode support in IIS6 and its FTP service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301710.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After some manual testing it does indeed seem to support Unicode/UTF encoding. Thought I still couldn't find a definitive reference.

Comment: Does it support localpart@domain.com example davé@domain.com?  I have not gotten it to work for sending email throws an exception.  .NET code is as follows - mMailMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress(recepient, recepient, Encoding.UTF8)) ----- Dim mSmtpClient As New SmtpClient()
        mSmtpClient.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International